# Inequality for Fourier coefficients

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform

Let $\mathbb{T}=\mathbb{R}/ \mathbb{Z}$ and let $I$ be an interval contained in $\mathbb{T}$. Let $\chi_I$ denote the characteristic function of $I$. Then why is the following true:

$\vert \hat{\chi}_I(k)\vert \leq \frac{1}{\pi\vert k \vert }$,

for every $k\in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$, where $ \hat{\chi}_I(k)=\int_{\mathbb{T}}\chi_I(x) e^{-i2\pi k x} dx $? I see that there is a trivial change of variable inside the integral, but I always get a larger upper bound.

Comment: How about you write down the trivial change of variables? I think it should work out

Comment: Maybe I am doing a stupid mistake, but I am proceeding as follows:

$\vert \int_\mathbb{T}\chi_I(x)e^{-i 2\pi k x}dx\vert =
\vert \int_{-\frac{1}{2}}^\frac{1}{2} \chi_I(x)e^{-i2\pi k x}dx\vert = \frac{1}{2 \pi \vert{k} \vert }\vert \int_{-\pi k}^{\pi k } \chi_I(\frac{s}{2 \pi k})e^{-is}ds\vert  $
$\leq \frac{1}{ \pi \vert{k} \vert } \int_{-\pi k}^{\pi k } \chi_{I \cdot 2 \pi k}(s)ds$. 

But then I major the term inside the integral changing $I$ with $ \left[ -\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2} \right]$ and I finally get 2 as an upperbound.

Comment: Your final inequality is too crude. Instead, simply calculate the integral explicitely: $|\int_{-\pi k}^{\pi k} \chi_{I}(s/(2\pi k)) \exp(-is)ds|=|\int_{a2\pi k}^{b2\pi k}\exp(-i s)ds|=|\exp(- i b2\pi k)-\exp(-ia2\pi k)|\leq 2$. Here $I=[a,b]$

Comment: @Bananach: Yes, indeed. Thank you.